# What is the benefit of Panels Everywhere

Tags: 7, theming, panels

Several websites advocate the benefits of Panels Everywhere (I have put them at the end of this question).

However, I have tried the module out out and cannot see the benefits.

A regular Panel page gives you the option to Disable Blocks. It also lets you display things like Menu Links, Footers and User Log-ins. 
So I'm not sure what Panels Everywhere brings.

[I could never see the benefits of Panels](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40225/what-is-the-benefits-of-panels-for-a-themer), but Drupal Answers enlightened me and now I wouldn't dream of making a Druapl site without it, so I'm hoping it can shed some light on the benefits of Panels Everywhere).

---

Sites Advocating Panels Everywhere

1. [AWebFactory](http://awebfactory.com.ar/node/435)
2. [Druapl Answers Thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26271/using-panels-everywhere-without-panels-everywhere)
3. [Lullabot](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/assembling-pages-with-drupal)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My experience with PE (panels everywhere) was great.
I been working for 1 year with PE on a big project and i can say:

- The first advantage of PE is the entire layout control. while panels only affect the "content" region, PE get full control of all page including header and footer (which is no possible only with panels).
- Second big advantage its the possibility to select variants as layouts letting you decide wich layout (variant) to show on every page taking that decision with the access arguments like a normal panel.

as you can see there are similarities with Omega theme, and in the fact both modules resolves the same issue.

Comment: +1 I've been working on a project using **Omega theme** to set the general layout using panels-like regions, **ctools Page Manager** to control the layout in each page's content area, and numerous **Mini Panels** placed as blocks for almost all the non-content layout... It works, but it feels increasingly like a clunky MacGuyvered impersonation of the features Panels Everywhere provide. That said, for sites with simple layouts, Panels Everywhere is probably overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the layout creation and management tools, there is another advantage to Panels: performance. Although not that apparent on smaller sites, it can have a major impact on larger installations. If a site is created using the standard Drupal block system, all blocks must load, and then not displayed (if set as so), instead of only pulling appropriate content for the given visitor.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main advantages of Panels Everywhere is that it lets you override pages that regular Panels does not allow (such as node/add, user, etc).